# Word that describes someone who knows that they've won before they've even started something?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call someone who knows that they've already won before they've even started? It's bordering on overly confident, but it's obvious that there is no way for them to lose since they believe that dying isn't a loss? 
I'm trying to describe a character that has a bomb inside her rib cage. It can only be activated through death. She doesn't care wether she lives or dies in battle because she knows that she will win.
Ex. "Mary doesn't care if she lives or dies since there is nothing to lose; in the end she will win all her battles. She is [...]."

Comment: Frame (example) sentence, please. And how exactly does "they believe that dying isn't a loss" fit in here?

Comment: We definitely need an example sentence to make sense of the *dying isn't a loss* part...

Comment: She must have pretty low self-esteem, or have some very severe enmity for her adversary, to consider mutual destruction to be “victory”.  And, unless your illustration is just the tip of the iceberg, she’s simplistic to the point of naivety — what if her adversary falls back and kills her from a distance?  Does her bomb have a blast radius greater than the range of a cruise missile?  What if she’s trapped under an avalanche? But you’re missing the point — we need ***an example sentence** that uses the word you want*.  We can’t tell whether you’re looking for a noun or an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

I would call such a person *invincible*.

M-W:

> [*invincible*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invincible):
>   incapable of being conquered, overcome, or subdued

Like your character, a person who is invincible cannot lose: even if they "lose", they win. Kind of like, when flipping a coin, I say, "Heads, I win. Tails, you lose."

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an adjective,

> [**self-assured**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self%E2%80%93assured), "having or showing confidence in yourself and your abilities"

approaches the meaning described.

A phrase would make it clearer:

> self-assured of victory.

It can also be expressed as:

> believe/consider/think oneself **the sure victor**.

Answer (score 0):

Several words come to mind. Without context or an example it's hard to know what you're looking for... Consider

- *temerarious*, from [temerity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temerity) [MWD]

  > the quality of being confident and unafraid of danger or punishment especially in a way that seems rude or foolish
- [daring](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daring) [MWD]

  > venturesomely bold in action or thought
- [brazen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brazen) [MWD]

  > acting or done in a very open and shocking way without shame or embarrassment
- [brash](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brash) [MWD]

  > confident and aggressive in usually a rude or unpleasant way

Answer (score -2):

Your protagonist could be ***fatalistic***:

> believing that you cannot prevent things from happening,
>   especially bad things
>                   [— Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fatalistic)
>
> Relating to or characteristic of the belief
>   that all events are predetermined and therefore inevitable.
>                   [— Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fatalistic)

although that clearly doesn’t capture the full scope of your request.